# Is the Ubuntu SDK suitable for desktop applications?

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, sdk

I'm interested in writing me first application for Ubuntu. I think using the Ubuntu SDK maybe the correct way. However, I'd like to confirm that the assumption to use the Ubuntu SDK is the best technology to use, before I embark on this work. I intend to writing an application intended for a desktop experience.

My programming experience to date is largely web technologies. I think to think of myself as a pretty proficient python programmer. Do I need experiences in any other languages before beginning?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" way to do anything. There's just different ways with advantages and disadvantages. Ubuntu SDK is a good option but there are many others too. Ubuntu SDK is based on the Qt framework which is a popular cross platform GUI framework, but is generally written using C++.

Another popular cross platform GUI framework is GTK, which has good bindings in Python using PyGTK.

Overall this question is going to be very opinionated because like I said, there is no "right" way to do it.